# RESTful HTTP Response from Eve appears empty in jQuery.getJSON

Tags: jquery, mongodb, rest, http, eve

I am trying to query MongoDB using eve with the tutorial example from python-eve.org. My jQuery

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/',  function(data, status){
});
alert(typeof(status) + " length of " + status.length);
```

only gives me 'status' as string with length 0. When trying to access 'data' within the function I get no response. I checked the syntax with

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/zombies',  function(data, status){
alert(data.description);        
});
```

which works fine. So next I watched how the requests are handled and used the Chrome Extension 'Advanced REST Client Application'. Both requests (to '127.0.0.1:5000/people/' and to facebook) give me the response HTTP Code 200 and the requested data.
In the terminal window where eve runs as a process the request (in the case of jQuery and through Chrome Extension) the console logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2015 14:47:49] "GET /people/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

which would indicate that the request is handled properly. Which leaves me with the question: Why can't I access the data object when trying with jQuery? Trying to add {"Accept":"application/json"} to the jQuery did not help.

Any suggestions are appreciated!
schuemax

Comment: The scope of the `status` variable works within $.getJSON(). But the variable outside declared as global variable

Comment: Thanks Tamil. I tried to access data and status within the function but received no response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was a conflict due to the same-origin-policy (SOM). Eve allows to define CORS and thus allowing the query. (see the docs).